# Cannot convert to int from string in php

Tags: javascript, php, string, integer

So I'm currently working on a piece of code which is rather stupidly misbehaving.

```
function screenWidth($buffer)
{
    global $widthTest;

    $widthTest = $buffer;

}

ob_start("screenWidth");

$screenWidth = '<script type="text/javascript">document.write(parseInt(document.documentElement.clientWidth));</script>';

echo $screenWidth;

$width = ob_get_contents();

ob_end_clean();

echo $width;
echo $widthTest;
```

This results in a string which gives me the screen width, without javascript, which is wonderful. However, for some reason, I can't get it to convert to a integer.

Am I missing something? I've run this in plain text and it's definitely returning the number and not just the javascript. It's being stored as a string, and if I try and convert it using intval or (int)$width; then it returns 0 every single time.

I'm aware of the pitfalls of doing things this way, but unfortunately this is legacy code and has to be done this way for a variety of reasons.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: I don't really see how this could work? The PHP code is being executed on the server first. Then it sends the result to the users browser where the javascript gets executed...  PHP can't get any value in return from that javascript.

Comment: This has been on this particular website for some time (not written by me originally), and I've been asked to update it. I had wondered if that was the case.

Comment: I guess it never worked. Somebody made a thought boo-boo on that one.

Answer (score 0):

It is **impossible** to get the screen width like this in PHP, as also mentioned by @MagnusEriksson, PHP is run on the server. At the time your PHP code is evaluated, the screen size is unknown. `javascript` runs at the **client**, where it can detect the screen size because the screen is an object of the client. PHP can never know the size of the screen because it is run on the server and on the server there is no screen (or at least not the correct one).

The only way to let PHP know the size of the screen of the client is by computing it using javascript, and then pass the value through using `ajax` or a redirect with the screen size as parameters `link.php?screensize=xxx`

---

In your current code, you already parse the javascript variable to an int. That works fine for the javascript variable (as can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/j47k01jt/).